# data binding not working in angular2

Tags: angular

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-content',
      templateUrl: `./app/content/content.components.html`
    })
    export class ContentComponent  { 
      _clickLectre: any;
      _temoobj:any;
      private subscription: Subscription;
      constructor(private commonService: CommonService, private dataService: DataService ) {
      }
      ngOnInit() {               
        this.subscription = this.commonService.notifyObservable$.subscribe((res) => {
          if (res.hasOwnProperty('option') && res.option === 'call_Lecture') {                         
                console.log("call"+res.items);            
                this._clickLectre=res.items;
                console.log("call"+this._clickLectre.facultyname);               
          }
        });
      }
      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }

    }
```

**html**

```
   <tr  *ngIf="_clickLectre">
    <td>Faculty Name : </td>
    <td>{{_clickLectre.facultyname}}</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>End Time :</td>
    <td>X </td>
    <td> Present: </td>
    <td>X </td>
   </tr>
```

I used `commonService` which use to transfer content from one Component to another  Component.

above `this._clickLectre.facultyname` value printed on console but it is not reflected on html page

why data binding not working  what is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `_clickLectrehero` does not appear to be declared or defined.

Comment: i am not using this  '_clickLectrehero' variable I used **_clickLectre**  which I declared already

Comment: It has been used in the `ngIf` in your template.

Comment: sorry I changed in question but still not work

Comment: How does your `CommonService` look like? Can you please try to add `private changeDetectorRef:ChangeDetectorRef` to the constructor parameters and call `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` after `this._clickLectre = res.item;`

Comment: thanks for reply mistake because of null value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `_clickLectre` is defined asynchronously you should use a safe navigation operator (`?`)

```
<td>{{_clickLectre?.facultyname}}</td>
```

Comment: I changed check this _clickLectre in ng-if but not work

Comment: @Pravin Are you putting the ? inside `{{_clickLectre?.facultyname}}`? Can you remove the ngIf and try that way?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your variable as empty object at initialization state.

```
_clickLectre = <any>{};
```